# Double pointer array allocation C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

I want to allocate an array for 6 words of a maximum of 30 charachters for example.

My teacher says I should allocate `6` "**+1**" to count for a `NULL` that I have to set **my self**
after inserting my words.

How exactly is a `char **array` is allocated and why is my teacher insisting ?

Comment: Did you do any research? There are many posts that ask the same/similar allocation question.

Comment: *My teacher says I should allocate 6 "+1" to count for a NULL*. You should ask the teacher that question. At a guess it is so you can iterate the array and know where it ends without knowing the size of the array beforehand.

Comment: @kaylum my teacher literally said " beacause i say so, and i won't accept the answer if you don't do what i say" which is better and whether i understand or not is not important clearly

Comment: In that case the full task requirements may tell us why that is needed. But you have not provided that so we can't say for sure. But as I said, it's likely to be for an end of array marker.

Comment: @kaylum about the linked post, no it doesn't help as I already know that a string should terminate with a '\0' but my question is regarding the first dimension. the number of cells i need to store n words and whether it is me that should add 1 more to terminate my first dim with NULL or whether it's already there

Comment: The post is not talking about terminating with NUL. It tells you how to allocate the first dimension of the array and then how to allocate the character array for each of those. Which is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @kaylum here's the original post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762325/problem-getting-dimensions-of-string-array-in-c

Comment: In it I count for a cell that I set to null after I finish storing my strings, in the comments, someone said that this is so wrong and since, I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your teacher wants you do use a null pointer at the end of the array, as a *sentinel value*. This is similar to null termination of individual strings and can sometimes be useful when the amount of strings is unknown.

When you allocate a single string you do `char* str = malloc(length + 1);` where the +1 is for the null terminator `'\0`. The extra +1 ensures that given `length = strlen("hello");`, we can safely do `strcpy(str, "hello")` to fill this string.

You can do something similar for an array of strings by
`char** arr = malloc(sizeof(char*[size+1]));`
If you then assign `arr[size] = NULL;` as sentinel value, it will be possible to iterate over this array in this way:

```
for(const char** ptr=arr; ptr!=NULL; ptr++)
{
  printf("%s\n", *ptr); // do something with each string
}
```

But if you know the size, then the preferred method is a normal loop:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
{
  printf("%s\n", arr[i]); // do something with each string
}
```

Comment: Your `malloc` should have the `+1` inside the square brackets, otherwise you're allocating only 1 byte for a pointer.

Comment: @interjay Yikes, of course, thanks. I made lots of other silly mistakes too. Note to self is not to write code from the top of my head when posting on SO, but always try it on a compiler even when it seems trivial :)

Answer (score -1):

`char **arr = calloc(7, sizeof(char*));`
So let's break this down, calloc basically makes an array, first argument is the size of the array and the second is how much memory to allocate to every index of the array.

Comment: This allocates an array of 7*6 chars and is not compatible with `char**`.

Comment: Why is it not compatible?

Comment: Because `char**` is supposed to point to an array of `char*`.

Comment: It should be `char **arr = calloc(7, sizeof(char*));`